# Is there a way to get actual Pod hostname in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, kube-prometheus-stack, kube-state-metrics

`kube_pod_labels` does populates `pod_label_node_name` and `pod_label_host_ip` for the given pod however the values don't correspond to the actual node name and ip of the pod.
Instead it represents the node name and ip for kube-state-metrics/node-exporter node.

As a result these values are to be same for all the pods.

What is the right way to get the actual node name and ip of the Pod in Prometheus?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have improper configuration for scraping `kube-state-metrics` target. This target must be scraped spearately from other pods, and it shouldn't have [relabeling rules](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling), which set `node`, `pod`, `container` and `namespace` labels, since these labels are already set to proper values by `kube-state-metrics` itself - see [these docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md). `kube-state-metrics` also sets labels based on pod annotations and pod labels, so these labels also shoudn't be set by relabeling config for `kube-state-metrics` target.

When `kube-state-metrics` is scraped correctly, then the hostname of every pod can be obtained via `node` and `host_ip` label at `kube_pod_info` metric - see [these docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md).